# Mathematica Table

Tags: matrix, code-request

I would like to do a table as shown in Mathematica but I am not sure the code that I need to use for that. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you [image]

Comment: Does `ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}], 1]` do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a formula for how the matrix 1/0 entries go, you can construct it using `Table`. In your case, it is not that difficult but it could be elusive in general, especially for higher dimensions and arbitrary shapes.

```
(t = With[{n = 12},
    Table[
     If[i == 1 || j == 1 ||
       i == n || j == n, 0, 1]
     , {i, n}
     , {j, n}]
    ]) // Grid
```

---

A variation building up on J.M.'s comment could be:

```
(s = With[{n = 12},
    CenterArray[
     ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}]
     , {n, n}
     ]
    ]) // Grid
```

---

Such matrices are used in image processing applications. Try:

```
(u = BoxMatrix[4, 12]) // Grid
```

Other good reads would be: `DiamondMatrix`, `CrossMatrix`, `DiskMatrix`

To display these matrices, you can explore the `ArrayPlot` command.

---

You can also generate such a matrix using `SparseArray` command, although in your case, it is not "sparse" enough.

```
n = 12;
(p = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (1 < i < n && 1 < j < n) -> 1}, {n, 
      n}] // Normal) // Grid
```

---

```
s == t == p == u  (* True *)
```

All the commands shown above generate the following:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$